# Why is this object variable undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have some really messy code I inherited that isn't working correctly. I did a `console.log` to find out why, and it tells me that my variable is undefined.

Here's the function - I've stripped out everything except the `console.log` for brevity.

```
function pageClick(pageToLoad, requestParams, origLoc, tag) {
    console.log("requestparams draw: " . requestParams.drawSideBar);
}
```

And here's the caller:

```
pageClick( "pizza", {drawSideBar: true} );
```

When I run the function, it tells me that `requestParams` is undefined. I'm not sure why; as far as I can see it's being passed a perfectly valid object. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but have no idea what it is.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php :)

Comment: @j08691 - the code I posted IS the shortest program necessary, and it can most certainly be reproduced. It is, as noted in the answers below, a typo resulting from not noticing that I used a php concat operator in a javascript function, but that doesn't mean it's not reproducible.

Comment: It boils down to a typo. `.` instead of `+`.

Comment: @CopyDevil - yeah, that was pointed out in the answers. I'm constantly moving between js and php, and sometimes I get operators and functions flipped.

Comment: @j08691 - yes, I'm aware it's a typo. But I'm betting it's a pretty common occurrence among those of us who work with more than one language so I don't imagine I'm the only one who'd be helped by the answer.

Comment: And I'm sure there are plenty of other questions on SO that have yet to be closed that cover the exact same typo. Don't worry too much about it, my vote alone can't close your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
console.log("requestparams draw: " . requestParams.drawSideBar);
                                   ^----- // Change . to +
```

Comment: Doh! I'm flipping back and forth between php and javascript. It's more obvious when I use `error_log` instead of `console.log`; I probably wouldn't have found this one.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
console.log("requestparams draw: ", requestParams.drawSideBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
console.log("requestparams draw: " + requestParams.drawSideBar);
```

inesated of

```
console.log("requestparams draw: " . requestParams.drawSideBar);
```